# Does DNSpython have a method that automatically performs a forward or reverse lookup depending on the value that it's passed?

Tags: python-3.x, dns, dnspython

I am wondering if there is a way to pass either a host, fqdn, or IP address to DNSPython and have it perform the proper lookup (forward for hosts and fqdns and reverse for ips). Also, I want to know what kind of address (host, fqdn, or ip) was sent to the method originally.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there's not a single function that will do what you're looking for. However, it wouldn't be too hard to implement. Here's how I'd probably do it.

First, I'd check if the input was an IP address

```
import ipaddress

def is_ipaddress(string):
    try:
        ipaddress.ip_address(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

If it is an IP address, then I'd call `dns.query.reverse_query()`. This is assuming I have installed the latest development version of dnspython from Github because `reverse_query()` was only recently added (see https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython/commit/7c105cce64699e1a221176f98f7cb9e682aba1e0).

If it's not an IP address, then I'd prepare my query with `dns.message.make_query(name, rdtype)` and then send it with `dns.query.udp()`.

If you wanted to use the value of search in /etc/reolv.conf, you might consider creating a  `dns.resolver.Resolver`, which currently does search processing by default.

```
import dns.resolver
import dns.rdatatype

resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
response = resolver.query('my-computer', dns.rdatatype.A)
```

Comment: Thank you! I modified the except clause to determine if the string is a FQDN or Host.
`
    except ValueError:
        if '.' in string:
            return 'FQDN'
        else:
            return 'Host'
`

Do you think that checking for a '.' is good enough to determine if something is an FQDN or should I check for something else?

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the bit about ValueError, I forgot what exception `ipaddress.ip_address` raises. I'm not sure I understand what the difference between "host" and "fqdn" is.